# Find multiple world in excel but just the exact word not which is containning

Tags: excel

I'm using

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"word1","word2","word3"},A1))),"YES","NO")
```

to find out the A column contains my words or not. But I just want to find the EXACT words. 
For example: one of my words is `and` and this formula says yes for `Andrea`. I don't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match only "word1" and not "sword1" or "word12"

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&{"word1","word2","word3"}&" "," "&A1&" "))),"YES","NO")`

...although punctuation in A1 could mess that up, is that a possibility?

Note: it isn't case-sensitive - if you want that too then change `SEARCH` to `FIND`

Answer (score 0):

White space trick.
Add space before and after your words.
Add space before and after A1.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" word1 "," word2 "," word3 "}," "&A1&" "))),"YES","NO")
```